# tabIndex for Div in Lighthning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am trying to apply for `tabIndex=-1` for the `div` but it is not applying using below code.

```
<div aura:id='lockDiv' style="pointer-events: none;">
    <ui:button/>
    <ui:button/>
</div>
```

in init controller i wrote like

```
component.find('lockDiv').set('v.tabIndex',-1);
```

inspect element tag

```
<div class="" id="caseAction" data-aura-rendered-by="823:0">
```

Please let me know if any solutions for this problem

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that, you can set some attributes to `SecureElement` after rendering it. `init` handler invokes after component construction but before rendering.  Check it - [Invoking Actions on Component Initialization](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_init_handler.htm)

> Use the init event to initialize a component or fire an event **after
>   component construction but before rendering.**

to add some attribute after successful render use handler for `render` event. Article - [Handle the render Event](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_render_handler.htm). to get DOM element, use [getElement](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_dom.htm?search_text=DOM) method

Your component should be:

```
<aura:handler name="render" value="{!this}" action="{!c.onRender}"/>
<div aura:id="lockDiv" style="pointer-events: none;">
    <ui:button/>
    <ui:button/>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
({
    onRender : function(component, event, helper) {
        var el = component.find("lockDiv").getElement();
        el.tabIndex = -1;
    }
})
```

as a result:

```
<div style="pointer-events: none;" data-aura-rendered-by="3:0" tabindex="-1"> 
    <button class="uiButton--default ...></button>
</div>
```